# Can I turn off a screen but leave the display working for a VNC Viewer?

Tags: c#, screen, logmein

I have been looking around for this but I can't find out if this is possible or not. I have some software that uses Log Me In Rescue. As it stands, the software currently connects to our servers to get a pin generated by their PHP API. This pin is then sent back to the application that then posts the form with the pin in at logmein123.com. This then downloads the response application, which then runs and our Support Techs can then access the hardware, the problem is the software actively cuts control of the Windows OS behind the application: no task bar; start button or driver installation; so the software then has provide a way for our support to re-enable every thing.

So I'm looking for a way to leave the display enabled to the LogMeIn software on the tills but stop the screen from showing is there I way I can tell the screen to turn off and not stop the display from working? The hardware is powered by a Windows 7-based OS. If this is possible, could some one point me to a tutorial on how to do such a thing?

Comment: If logmein has support for RDP (remote desktop protocol) then the client is "logged out" off their pc and you take over their session. They see the log in screen. It's not exactly what you want but it's the closest thing I know.

Comment: It does not use RDP it uses there own Desktop Streaming Protocol that does not lock the user out please go look up Log Me In Rescue before jumping the the conclusion it was an RDP system

Comment: Just to clarify i said VNC viewer as that is also a DSP not an RDP